# PHP Word followed by a numeric value

Tags: php, string

I have the following example address string:

```
$address1 = "Flat 2 House Name 21 Another Road";
```

If the string has the word Flat followed by a numeric value, then I would like to place a coma straight after the numeric value. Next, I would like to see if there are other instances of a numeric value and if so add a coma before every other numeric value. So the example above needs to change to this:

```
"Flat 2, House Name, 21 Another Road"
```

Comment: What have tried so far? The way that this site works is that you post some code, explain a problem that you are having with it and we try to help you to solve the problem. We are **not** a code writing service. For that, you can go to https://www.elance.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

```
 <?php

$address1 = "Fre 2 House Name 21 Another Road";

$ex = explode(' ', $address1);
$cant = 0;
$out = '';

for($i = 0; $i < count($ex); $i++) {

    if(is_numeric($ex[$i])) {
        $cant++;

            if($cant == 1 && $ex[$i - 1] == 'Flat') {
      $out .= ' ' . $ex[$i] . ', ';
  } else {
      $out = trim($out);
      $out .=  ', ' . $ex[$i] . ' ';
  }

    } else {
        $out .= $ex[$i] . ' ';
}
}

echo $out;

?>
```

Comment: It works but seems to combine the House Name as HouseName. Any idea where it's going wrong? Oh, i figured it out, i chaged the last $out .= to $out .= $ex[$i].' ';

Comment: just realised there is another issue, it seems to be checking for the first numeric value and then adding a comma, but it needs to check that the word flat is there before it.

Comment: can you provide some example, edit your post please, and if there is not the word Flat? What happens?

Comment: I edit again, you made me work, I hope at least you vote up ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
        $s="Flat 2 House Name 21 Another Road";
        echo preg_replace('@(flat \d+)@i','$1,',$s);
```

edited ( sorry - didn't see that this was supposed to insert the other commas before subsequent  numerics )

```
    $s="The Flat 2 House Name 21 Another Road";
    echo preg_replace('@(\sflat \d+|\d+)@i','$1,',$s);
```

This seems to work as you required.

```
    $search=array(
        '@(?<=flat)\s(\d+)@i',
        '@(?<!flat)\s(\d+)@i'
    );
    $replace=array( ' $1,', ', $1' );
    echo preg_replace( $search, $replace, $s );
```

The above ( final ) version uses lookbehind regex patterns. The initial pattern is a positive 'lookbehind' pattern that says 'Match numbers that are preceded by flat' and the second is a negative lookbehind and says 'Match numbers that are NOT preceded by flat' which is what you were after i think. The 'i' switch makes it case-insensitive. The '$1' is a backreference to the first captured subpattern.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not placing a coma before every additional numeric value. Also, it's not looking for the word Flat by itself, so if i put word like TheFlat, it still matches the above rule, but it needs to be Flat by itself

Comment: Thanks for the edit, the comma for all the subsequent numerics need to be before the numeric value as apposed to the comma after the numeric flat value. is it possible to do this?

Comment: all things are possible - but it's late and i'm off to my bed. You might want to look at using arrays as pattern and replacement values in preg_replace - tweaking the above